# how to Exclude parent Id from parent child query result

Tags: apex

Below Query returns parent_Id_c and Id from child record, even though fields wasn't listed in the  query.How to avoid system from returning parentId or is it possible to remove parentId field reference from the child record.

```
obja = [select id,(select name__c from child__r) from parent where id = parent.ID]

objb = a.child__r
```

when objb printed in debug log the result as follows.

```
child__c:{parent_Id__c=a1DM000003ND2C, Id= a1CM0000003Kg8nM, Name__c=test}
```

Comment: You always get `Id`, it is impossible to remove from query results. The same is apparently true for child sub-queries.

Comment: @AdrianLarson you're absolutely correct. Id is always returned. I can't find the documentation on this, but I know it's been this way since approximately forever. You should write up an answer for it. Also, SOSL always returns ID values, too.

Comment: @sfdcfox i can only remove id by cloning child record  to a different object but it is still retaining  parentId from the cloned child record.

Comment: whats ur actual use case & why do you want to exclude those fields ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna  I am trying to insert both parent and child records in single DML Statement using external id of parent, when any changes happen to the values in existing  parent or child records.

Comment: You cannot possibly insert parent and child records at the same time. You need the parent's `Id` to make the child relationship...

Answer (score 0):

You always get `Id`, it is impossible to remove from query results. The same is apparently true for child sub-queries.

You could theoretically remove it yourself through post-processing.

```
Parent__c parent = [
    SELECT (Select Name__c FROM Children__r)
    FROM Parent__c WHERE Id = :parentId
];
system.assertNotEquals(null, parent.Id);
for (Child__c child : parent.Children__r)
{
    system.assertNotEquals(null, child.Id);
    system.assertNotEquals(null, child.Parent__c);
    child.Id = null;
    child.Parent__c = null;
    system.assertEquals(null, child.Id);
    system.assertEquals(null, child.Parent__c);
}
```

Note that the above will cause updates to fail, because you are clearing out the `Id` value. Your question does not make clear why you do not want these values, so it is hard to recommend a best course of action.

Comment: Actually i want  to remove remove the parentID field reference from child object but not just value of the parentId.  scenario is that when ever any changes happen to the values in existing parent or child records  system has to insert both parent and child records at same time using single DML statement.

Comment: @vraavi That is completely impossible.

Comment: is there any better solution to handle this scenario rather than inserting parent and child separately. There are bunch of child records associated to parent so I don't like to iterate all child records to assign parentId before insert.

Comment: @vraavi It is extremely unclear what you are trying to accomplish through this functionality. Please clarify the underlying use case. What is your desired business outcome?

Comment: @vraavi - while APEX can manage object relationships in memory, SFDC DML can only operate on a single sObject type per call.